# Sharepoint : Is there a webpart filter that supports wildcards?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library with a custom column named "compound" which is just text.

I want to put a filter (input text box) on that document library page so the view shows only the items where the compound column contains my typed-in text.  Optimally, wildcards such as * or ? or full regular expressions could be supported... but for now, I just need a "contains".

The out-of-the-box text filter seems to only support an exact match.

The result output would be identical to what I would see if I created a new view, and added a filter with a "contains" clause.

Third party solutions are acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

KWizCom has a filter web part that looks like it might do what you want:
[KWizCom SharePoint List Filter Plus](http://www.kwizcom.com/ProductPage.asp?ProductID=404&ProductSubNodeID=405)

Another option to try is using a SharePoint Designer Data View Web Part.  I believe you can write the filter with a "contains" from SPD.

Answer (score 2):

I know you can set up this kind of filter more easily if you add the normal List View to a page, and the edit it with SharePoint Designer. In SPD, you can set up a "begins with" filter. Here's a [discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomization/thread/fbd25b4b-abb4-431c-b8c2-7385639a0b51/) where someone suggested the same thing.